# Hasse diagram max/greatest,topological sort

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, order-theory

A set S of jobs can be ordered by writing x≤y to mean that iether x = y or x must be done before y, for all x and y in S. given the hasse diagram, for this relation for a particular set S of jobs, show the following:

a) minimal,least,maximal and greatest elements

b) topological sort.

[image]

My answer:

a)

minimal: 1,9,2

maximal: 3

least: none

greatest:3

b)

topological order: (1,9,2,10,6,8,5,7,4,3)

Is this correct? or am i completely off

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: How is topological order defined?